# Cannot open database requested by the login

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Изучаю ASP.Net Core MVC по книге Адама Фримена.

Пробую запускать [этот пример](https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-mvc/tree/master/Source%20Code%201-31/08%20-%20SportsStore), но получаю ошибку следующего содержания:

> Cannot open database "SportsStore" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-TS09MR6\AdminX'.

*ConnectionString* выглядит так `Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=SportsStore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true`

В чем может быть проблема?

StackTrace:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "SportsStore" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-TS09MR6\AdminX'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.GetResult[TResult](IEnumerable`1 valueBuffers)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1.b__0(QueryContext qc)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Any[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at SportsStore.Models.SeedData.EnsurePopulated(IApplicationBuilder app) in F:\Рабочий стол\pro-asp.net-core-mvc-master\Source Code 1-31\08 - SportsStore\SportsStore\src\SportsStore\Models\SeedData.cs:line 12
   at SportsStore.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in F:\Рабочий стол\pro-asp.net-core-mvc-master\Source Code 1-31\08 - SportsStore\SportsStore\src\SportsStore\Startup.cs:line 43
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема разрешилась.

Перенес код инициализации БД в метод `Main`, как указано [здесь](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9597#event-1297454841).

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = BuildWebHost(args);

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

        try
        {
            var context = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            SeedData.EnsurePopulated(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
        }
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

После этого команды `Add-Migration Initial` и `Update-Database` в консоли менеджера пакетов отработали нормально. БД создалась и ошибка пропала.

Comment: А можете пожалуйста более подробно расписать ход исправления ошибки?

Comment: @PanchosP, К сожалению уже не вспомню.

Comment: @PanchosP, Лучше создайте свой вопрос и опишите проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема явно описана в сообщении об ошибке: SQL Server не смог подключить пользователя DESKTOP-TS09MR6\AdminX к базе SportsStore потому что такой базы на сервере нет. Или она есть, но у пользователя DESKTOP-TS09MR6\AdminX нет прав на доступ к ней (маловероятно для локального админа и localdb).

Подключитесь к серверу через Visual Studio или SSMS и создайте базу с таким именем.

Comment: Разве EF не должен создавать базу сам?

Comment: @maxwell зависит от того, какой database initializer прописан.

Comment: @maxwell а вообще - в какой момент вы ошибку получаете? при запуске отладки по F5? Какой стектрейс?

Comment: Да, при запуске отладки. Добавил стектрейс в вопрос.

Comment: @mawell, Насколько я понял из книги в этом примере база должна создаться автоматически, ибо автор о ручном создании ничего не говорил и сразу после конфигурации EF он добавляет миграции. А у меня на этом этапе начинаются ошибки.

Comment: @maxwell дело в том, что EF как-то должен узнать, есть база или нет. единственный способ это проверить - подключится к ней. А при этом возникает first chance exception (который ловит catch-ем сам EF). Причем делает он это несколько раз. Скорее всего вас в опциях отладчика снят Enable Just My Code и выставлен чекбокс для SqlException / TargetInvocationException. И вы видите внутренее исключение. Просто запустите не под отладкой - скорее всего поможет. или Enable Just My Code временно поставьте.

Comment: Не помог ни запуск без отладки, ни снятие чекбокса "Enable Just My Code". Наткнулся на [эту статью](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db), в которой также, как и в книге, сначала создаются модели, а затем добавляются миграции через менеджер пакетов. И после добавления миграций база и должна создаться, но в менеджере пакетов у меня та же самая ошибка.

Comment: @maxwell локализуйте проблему. сведите ее к куску кода, который можно будет скопировать в новый проект (желательно, консольное приложение) - и получить ошибку. и укажите версию EF.